# Get ng-model in ng-repeat in ng-repeat with Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, bdd, cucumberjs

How can I get the ng-model in ng-repeat in ng-repeat with protractor ?

```
<div ng-repeat="field in master.linker | orderBy:'country.name'">
    <div>
        <p> {{ field.country_name }} </p>

            <label ng-repeat="user in user_list">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected_user">
                <span ng-bind="user.name"></span>
            </label>

    </div>
</div>
```

I use filter() to check my ng-repeat :

```
var fields = element.all(by.repeater('field in master.linker'));

fields.filter(function (field) {
    return field.element(by.binding("field.country_name")).getText().then(function (country) {
        return country === "en";
    });
}).then(function (filteredFields) {

    var fields2 = filteredFields[0].element.all(by.repeater('user in user_list'));

    return fields2.filter(function (field2) {
        return field2.element(by.binding('user.name')).getText().then(function (value) {
            return value === user;
        });
    }).then(function (filteredFields) {
        var myuser = filteredFields[0].element(by.model('user_name'));

        self.current_step.expect(input.getAttribute('value')).to.eventually.equal('');

    });

});;
```

I have this error in my console :

```
TypeError: filteredFields[0].element.all is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.all()` instead of `.element.all()`:

```
filteredFields[0].all(by.repeater('user in user_list'));
```

You can also simplify things using `first()`:

```
var fields = element.all(by.repeater('field in master.linker'));
var filteredUser = fields.filter(function (field) {
    return field.element(by.binding("field.country_name")).getText().then(function (country) {
        return country === "en";
    });
}).first().all(by.repeater('user in user_list')).filter(function (userField) {
    return userField.element(by.binding('user.name')).getText().then(function (value) {
        return value === user;
    });
}).first();

var myuser = filteredUser.element(by.model('user_name'));
self.current_step.expect(myuser.getAttribute('value')).to.eventually.equal('');
```

You may also look into the [`column()` and `row()` repeater API](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater).

Comment: Thx, I use thiscode but it doesn't work, my tests are always true. I write an console log in my function filteredUser, but I don't see it.

Comment: @JérémieChazelle thanks, what do you mean by you cannot see it? Note that if you want to print a real value of the `value` attribute, you need to resolve the promise: `myuser.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) { console.log(value); });`.

Comment: with filteredFields[0].all(by.repeater('user in user_list')); it works ! Thx @alecxe